# Assert_Difference Rails Test Failing to Verify User Deleted but seems to Work in App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am following through with the [Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users) but am struggling with verifying that a user is destroyed when issuing a delete request to the user path with this test.

When I boot up the app on Cloud 9 and physically go into the All users index and delete a user, it does disappear so this has been a bit of a road block at the moment !

Here is the user_index_test.rb file

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersIndexTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

def setup
   @user = users(:Robert)
   @admin     = users(:Robert)
   @non_admin = users(:archer)
end

test "index as admin including pagination and delete links" do
  log_in_as(@admin)
  get users_path
  assert_template 'users/index'
  first_page_of_users = User.paginate(page: 1)
  first_page_of_users.each do |user|
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(user)
    unless user == @admin
      assert_select user_path(user), :text => 'delete'
    end
  end

  assert_difference 'User.count', -1 do
    delete user_path(@non_admin)
  end
end
end
```

Here is the index.html.erb file

```
  <ul class="users">
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <li>
        <%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
        <%= link_to user.name, user %>
        <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
          <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                 data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
        <% end %>
      </li>
      <% end %>
  </ul>
  <%= will_paginate %>
```

The error code:

```
      ....................................DEPRECATION WARNING: The assertion 
  was not run because of an invalid css selector.
  unexpected '950961012' after 'CHILD_SELECTOR' (called from block (2  
  levels) in <class:UsersIndexTest> at 
 /home/ubuntu/workspace/test/integration/users_index_test.rb:19)
  F...

    1) Failure:
  UsersIndexTest#test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links       
  [/home/ubuntu/workspace/test/integration/users_index_test.rb:23]:
  "User.count" didn't change by -1.
  Expected: 1
  Actual: 2
```

I have tried changing the assert_select to a[href=], a[href], a few more after looking at the source to remove the depreciation warning but to no avail. Been stuck here for a few days now figure I'd ask.

Any help appreciated :)

UPDATE 1: 
As @UriAgassi pointed out there was an issue was with my assert_select statement failing, resulting in Rails NOT selecting the correct tag and therefore not putting through a DELETE request.

So I am attempting to create a new assert_select command but the trouble is, the `<a>` tag I am trying to select is right after an anchor tag.

New User Index Test:

```
    first_page_of_users.each do |user|
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(user), :text => user.name
      unless user == @admin
         assert_select "a[class=?]", 'user', :test => 'delete'
      end
    end
```

The HTML Page

```
     <li>
       <img alt="Robert" class="gravatar"   
 src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/e831ff7d5e2cad2c7da9249aa28343c9?s=50" />
       <a href="/users/1">Robert</a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <img alt="Dr. Lonzo Rosenbaum" class="gravatar" 
 src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/ef4fac9f70a2ad49b02546f3aa416a61?s=50" />
       <a href="/users/3">Dr. Lonzo Rosenbaum</a>
       **<!-- User to delete, tag to select class="user"-->**
         <a class="user" data-confirm="You sure?" 
          rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/3">delete</a>
     </li>
```

New Error Message:

```
     1) Failure:
 UsersIndexTest#test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links 
 [/home/ubuntu/workspace/test/integration/users_index_test.rb:19]:
 Expected at least 1 element matching "a[class="user"]", found 0..
 Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

Comment: isn't the error referring to the other `assert_select`? `assert_select user_path(user), :text => 'delete'`

Comment: Chapter 9: Section 9.4.3

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like that the test is not correctly calling the destroy action
Try it like this:

```
delete :destroy, id: @non_admin.id
```

Comment: Hey Meier, thanks for your answer. Gave that a try no luck, same error message. 

Combined it with SickLickWill's syntax correction suggestion now receiving: 



`1) Error:
 
     UsersIndexTest#test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links:
     URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?):    
     http://www.example.com:80destroy
         test/integration/users_index_test.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in   

    <class:UsersIndexTest>'
         test/integration/users_index_test.rb:23:in `block in   
    <class:UsersIndexTest>' `

Comment: Ok, my suggestion was the syntax for functional tests, for your integration test your syntax should work.

Comment: Any additional ideas? Still really stuck here. 

If not, would you advise continuing on and ignoring the bug/test for now?

Comment: Just the opposite: learn to use a debugger. check what delete returns. Check how you can access the status code. check that your destroy method is run. This will take time, but you really learn something.

Comment: Hey Meier, I think I found the issue, my assert_select was failing. 

So I am attempting to write a new assert_select statement that targets an <a> tag which comes just after another <a> tag both with the same href.

Tried adding and selecting a class="user" but keep getting error message. 

See the above edits.

Answer (score 0):

You have a small syntax error that is likely breaking your test on line 19:

```
assert_select user_path(user), :text => 'delete'
```

This should be:

```
assert_select user_path(@user), :text => 'delete'
```

Comment: Hi SickLickWill! 

Thanks for your suggestion. Gave it a try, same error was returned. 

Any suggestions and/or additional code you think could help? 

Thanks!